# datetime-local to Date from form to Spring

Tags: javascript, java, spring, datetime, validation

I have in my form a input:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="enddate" name="endDate" class="form-control" placeholder="endDate">
```

And in Spring:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date endDate;
```

And after submit I have a error:
rejected value [2022-10-19T12:21]; codes [typeMismatch.threads.endDate,typeMismatch.endDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]
..
[Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'

I have to keep the pattern and type Date in Spring.
Somebody know how to convert this input in form to send Date not text ?

Thanks You

Regards

Edit:

2022-10-17 12:34:20.614  WARN 12128 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errorsField error in object 'threads' on field 'endDate': rejected value [2022-10-28T12:34];
codes [typeMismatch.threads.endDate,typeMismatch.endDate,typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDateTime,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [threads.endDate,endDate]; arguments []; default message [endDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'endDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2022-10-28T12:34'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2022-10-28T12:34]]]

Comment: Change `Date` to `java.time.LocalDateTime` or another class from the `java.time` package

Comment: Error is the same:
`codes [threads.endDate,endDate]; arguments []; default message [endDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'endDate';`

Comment: Please add the complete Stacktrace to your question

Comment: I Eddited a question

Comment: Your date time format - `dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss` does not match the format of the actual date - `2022-10-28T12:34`. Either fix the format in the annotation to match input format, or fix the incoming date to be in correct format matching the annotation.

Comment: I do: 
`@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm")
    private Date endDate;` (LocalDateTime too) and problem is still exist Spring see a String not a Date type

Answer (score 0):

I changed a pattern to iso and type Date to LocalDateTime and it's work

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime endDate;
```